# URLRequest fewer characters

Tags: ios, swift, urlrequest

I'm trying to fetch some weather data ([Location forecast](http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.33895;lon=5.96639)). This request return a couple of kb. OK, so I would only like to request the first part or terminate the request when i get the line

```
<temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="xxxx"/>
```

Is it possible to do a URLRequest in iOS Swift that request a certain number of bytes/chars. Or is put into chunks and then terminated when temperature is received. I could setup a server acting as proxy and cut down the data exchanged to my app, but it would be nice if I could avoid this.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/urlsession-background-downloads/) Why are you worried about a few kB?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should implement a solution and see how it works out. Then put in a proxy if the performance sucks. I think ~180 KB is a lot when I (for the moment) only need the temperature.

Comment: I checked and got ~150kB. That's indeed more data than `a couple of kB` as you wrote. Doesn't the API allow sending you back much less data? Good luck! With >150kB you should be able to limit data usage by stopping the download request. Be aware that's hacky to search for a string in an XML file, instead of parsing the data.